# Can't resolve all parameters for GlobalsService: (?)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to use a service to store information that is globally used. At the moment it should just contain the current user.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from "../user/user.service";

import {User} from "../user/user";

@Injectable()
export class GlobalsService {
    private currentUser: User = null;      

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user);
    }
}
```

This is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {routing} from "./app.routing";

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {UserModule} from "./user/user.module";

import {CanActivateViaOAuthGuard} from "./auth/oAuth.canActivateGuard";

import {GlobalsService} from './globals/globals.service';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing, UserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [GlobalsService, CanActivateViaOAuthGuard]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Now I get this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for GlobalsService: (?).
    Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GlobalsService: (?).
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata
```

**EDIT:**

The UserService is provided by the `user.module.ts` :

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {UserComponent} from "./user.component";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {UserService} from './user.service';

@NgModule({
    providers:[UserService],
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [UserComponent],
    exports: [UserComponent]
})

export class UserModule{}
```

If I remove the `UserService` from the constructor of `GlobalsService` the error disappears.

The UserService:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import {AuthHttp} from "../auth/authHttp.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {User} from "./user";
import {GlobalsService} from "../globals/globals.service";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private url: string = this.globals.getServerUrl() + 'users';

    constructor(private http: AuthHttp, private globals: GlobalsService) {
    }

    getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }

    getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get(this.url + '/me');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's it supposed to be getting the `UserService` from? The `UserModule`? Is it being correctly exported? Could you give more of a [mcve]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited the post. I hope it is what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Put **UserService** in providers of **AppModule** and annotate it with @Injectable

Comment: The **UserService** hast the @Injectable() and should be provided through the **user.module.ts** .
Also if I put the **UserService** in the providers of **AppModule** it doesn't help.

Comment: Why you are injecting GlobalsService in UserService? You are creating cross referencing with it. Create Shared module and include GlobalService in it, that module you can provide in UserModule, AppModule or whenever

Comment: When I do this, how can I access the **GlobalsService** inside the **UserService**?